# Bouncing UITableView causes crash

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm working on an iPhone app that uses RSS.
When I scroll my `UITableView`, if I bounce it to the bottom too much, my app crashes and I get `__TERMINATING_DUE_TO_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION__`.

Here is my code:
http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~abc329/SS/

Here is the error I get:

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for 
 "/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit" (file not found).

warning: Unable to read symbols from 
 "UIKit" (not yet mapped into memory).

warning: Unable to read symbols for 
  "/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics" (file not found).

warning: Unable to read symbols from 
  "CoreGraphics" (not yet mapped into memory).
Program loaded.
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all

Attaching to program: `/Users/abc329/Library/Application Support/
                      iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/
                      D1B397C8-9464-4979-9F12-4302A502680E/
                      street-spotted.app/street-spotted', process 18528.

(gdb)
```

Comment: Please tag the question appropriately - language, etc.

Comment: This does not help at all. Did you try to isolate the issue? Also, what you've posted are warnings. Did you get a runtime error (SIGSEGV, pehaps)?